# What means "flowControl options do not persist across subscription instances"?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub

Google Cloud pubsub 0.14.5 [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/pubsub/0.14.5/pubsub/topic?method=subscription) says, that "flowControl options do not persist across multiple instances".

What does it mean?

Does it mean, that if you get subscriptions (e.g. with getSubscriptions), you always receive subscriptions without flowControl options and you need to set them somehow?

Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Instance" in this case means logical node.js subscription instance (created e.g. with `createSubscription` method).

So "flowControl options do not persist across multiple instances" means, that subscription options must be set for each subscription instance.

Currently there are two methods to set subscription options: `subscription` and `createSubscription`

There might be also `setOptions` method in the future:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/2723#issuecomment-341993187